# Variable in filter query in Jaydata

Tags: database, sqlite, jaydata

I have a string which I need to pass in filter query of Jaydata.Kindly guide..
Here is my following code:

```
var string = ((id=4 || id>6)&& (Name contains 'a'));
mydb.Document.filter(function(result){
    return result.str;
}).toArray(function(abc){
console.log(abc);
});
```

Here mydb is sQlite db instance name and Document is table name.
Error comes when I use result.str as str is not the field name of the table.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

your filter is not correct, also you can pass parameter with referring the second parameter, like this

```
mydb.Document.filter(function(result){
     return result.str == this.foo;
}, { foo: 'bar'}).toArray(function(abc){
```

of course, instead of 'bar' you can pass any value